# Coefficient of $x^3$ in $(1+2x-x^2+3x^3)^4$ and $(1+2x-x^2+3x^3+4x^4)^4$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

Let $a$ and $b$ be the coefficient of $x^3$ in $(1+2x-x^2+3x^3)^4$ and $(1+2x-x^2+3x^3+4x^4)^4$ respectively. Then find the value of $a-b$.

My approach is as follow

$T=2x-x^2+3x^3$

$T^2=x^2(2-x+3x^2)^2$

$T^3=x^3(2-x+3x^2)^3$

$T^4=x^4(2-x+3x^2)^4$

$(1+T)^4=^4C_0+^4C_1T+^4C_2T^2+^4C_3T^3+^4C_4T^4$

After this step not able to approach as it is getting complicated

Comment: Hint: this is the same as finding the coefficient of $x^3$ in the difference of those polynomials. Try to factor that difference a bit. The numbers are chosen perfectly in this problem to avoid a lot of messy algebra, if you use this insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A = 1 + 2x - x^2 + 3x^3$ and $B = 4x^4$ then the difference of your both polynomials is:

$$
\begin{align}
A^4 - (A+B)^4 &= A^4 - (A^4 + 4A^3B + 6A^2B^2 + 4AB^3 + B^4) \\
&= -4A^3B - 6A^2B^2 - 4AB^3 - B^4
\end{align}
$$

Because $B$ has $x^4$, all polynomial terms with a multiple of $B$ have no coefficient for $x^c$ with $c < 4$. Therefore all the coefficients $0$ to $3$ of the difference polynomial are garanteed to be $0$.

Therefore $a - b = 0$.

Comment: Or as a slightly different way of saying the same thing, $1+2x-x^2+3x^3 \equiv 1+2x-x^2+3x^3+4x^4 \pmod{x^4}$ implies $(1+2x-x^2+3x^3)^4 \equiv (1+2x-x^2+3x^3+4x^4)^4 \pmod{x^4}$ (these equivalences being in a polynomial ring such as $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ or $\mathbb{Q}[x]$).